# Git alias that takes an argument in PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell

I want to create a git alias through command line that can take an argument. There are a lot of examples out there that use an anonymous bash function, but I can't find any that works in PowerShell.

What I have tried is something like this:

```
git config --global alias.test '!& { param($msg) Write-Host $msg }'
```

Running `git test "Hello"` results in:

```
> git test "Hello"
& { param($msg) Write-Host $msg }: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
& { param($msg) Write-Host $msg }: -c: line 0: `& { param($msg) Write-Host $msg } "$@"'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @PetSerAl, that's what I needed. If you can post this as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @CookieMonster what was the solution?